# Is there a way to make the Firefox address bar only show the first level URL the user visited before?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, address-bar

Is there a way to make the Firefox address bar only show the first level URL the user visited before?

If I visited `www.example.com`, I hope that whenever I type <kbd>e</kbd>, it will only show `www.example.com` and not `www.example.com/sub/sub/sub/***`.

Is there an add-on or trick to do that?

Comment: I can confirm that there is no core feature in Firefox that does this (for example, via a pref). I should also add that, for the most part, this type of "simplified" navigation is not going to work for most users, even the type of users I presume you want to configure this for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's for your frequently visited websites, you can add them as bookmarks (say make a bookmark folder with just these "url hacks").

After that, your URL bar will show the bookmarked (root) url as first result.

Comment: This is a nice tip. I notice that too but didn't relate it to this problem. I will mark this as the answer.